# Which OpenGL library should i use and why?

Tags: opengl

CPW, FLTK, Freeglut, GLFW, GLEW, GLOW Toolkit, GLT and GlutMaster, GLUI UI Library, NGL or SDL? 
Which one should i use? What's the difference?
 Do they have any official library?
Is it possible to directly use OpenGL without all these libs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> CPW, FLTK, Freeglut, GLFW, GLEW, GLOW Toolkit, GLT and GlutMaster, GLUI UI Library, NGL or SDL?

Each of these libraries does someting entirely different; although you can kind of group them into categories

- ***GLUT, GLFW, SDL:** These are for creating a window with a OpenGL context and UI event management
- **FLTK, CPW:** full blown frameworks that provide window management, event dispatching widgets and more
- **GLEW:** OpenGL extension loader library. Simplfies the process of loading modern OpenGL feature. Can be done without, but becomes tedios. GLEW is kind of outdated and there are better alternatives, like glLoadGen.
- **NGL:** seems to be a teaching library, kind of a framework as well.
- **GLT:** which one do you mean, there are several "GLT" libraries out there (I'm guilty of one).

> Which one should i use?

That depends on what you need.

> What's the difference?

Some of them create windows and OpenGL contexts. Others provide you with widgets, and others are helpers to make your life easier.

> Is it possible to directly use OpenGL without all these libs?

**YES!** But it quickly becomes tedious.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! How do i use OpenGL directly?

Comment: Depends on the environment, what os are you planning to use it on?